# Select categories where no product has inventory

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-relationship, iqueryable

I am trying to wrap my head around a Linq query to return a parent object only if all child objects contain a specific property.

I.e., as an example, return categories where all products linked to that category have `product.Inventory == 0`

Other title for this Q:
Select ParentObject where all ChildObjects have specific ChildObject.Parameter value

EDIT:
In addition to the relationship, I also only want to get a category if one of it's date properties is not null.

EDIT:
Here is one of the samples I have previously attempted:

```
var selectQuery = 
   (from statementDetail in pcardDatabaseContext.PCardStatementDetails
    where statementDetail.ExportedDate != null
    && statementDetail.PCardTransactions.All(txn => txn.TransactionStatusID == txnStatusAccountingApproved)
    orderby statementDetail.ExportedDate
    select statementDetail) as IOrderedQueryable<PCardStatementDetail>;
```

EDIT:
Found a solution for my problem, but can't self-answer for another 7 hours.

I had partially been experiencing some issues on an earlier syntax, I assumed that when using `x.All` the values wouldn't return any match if the set was empty.

Here is what solved it for me:

```
var selectQuery =
   (from statementDetail in pcardDatabaseContext.PCardStatementDetails
    where statementDetail.ExportedDate == null
    && statementDetail.PCardTransactions.All(txn => txn.TransactionStatusID == txnStatusAccountingApproved)
    && statementDetail.PCardTransactions.Any()
    orderby statementDetail.ExportedDate
    select statementDetail) as IOrderedQueryable<PCardStatementDetail>;
```

Please note that I had modified the `ExportDate` to only retrieve `ExportedDate == NULL`.
Also, I had to add a `.Any`, otherwise I was getting records that had no Transactions (where I thought the `.All` would filter out).

Comment: Here is an example that I have previously attempted. Could you let me know if this should work?  `code`var selectQuery = (from statementDetail in pcardDatabaseContext.PCardStatementDetails
                               where statementDetail.ExportedDate != null
                                    && statementDetail.PCardTransactions.All(txn => txn.TransactionStatusID == txnStatusAccountingApproved)
                               orderby statementDetail.ExportedDate
                               select statementDetail) as IOrderedQueryable<PCardStatementDetail>;`code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem, but can't self-answer for another 7 hours.

I had partially been experiencing some issues on an earlier syntax, I assumed that when using `x.All` the values wouldn't return any match if the set was empty.

Here is what solved it for me:

```
var selectQuery =
   (from statementDetail in pcardDatabaseContext.PCardStatementDetails
    where statementDetail.ExportedDate == null
    && statementDetail.PCardTransactions.All(txn => txn.TransactionStatusID == txnStatusAccountingApproved)
    && statementDetail.PCardTransactions.Any()
    orderby statementDetail.ExportedDate
    select statementDetail) as IOrderedQueryable<PCardStatementDetail>;
```

Please note that I had modified the `ExportDate` to only retrieve `ExportedDate == NULL`.
Also, I had to add a `.Any`, otherwise I was getting records that had no Transactions (where I thought the `.All` would filter out).

Answer (score 2):

```
var categoriesWithNoInventory =
    Categories.Where(c => c.Products.All(p => p.Inventory == 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your classes look something like this

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Inventory { get; set; }
}
```

then this will work (AllCategories() returns `IEnumerable<Category>`)

```
var categories = AllCategories().Where(c => c.Products.All(p => p.Inventory == 0));
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm trying to perform the filtering in a single Queryable, before enumerating the Objects.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to do 2 queries? the first to grab the child products and then to check the inventory, or I suppose you could do it with a join, here's a join example: http://www.dotnetperls.com/join

Comment: I saw that sample. I have been experiencing some trouble getting it right. Tried doing some joins and groupJoins too...

Comment: I realize you can't leave comments yet, but this isn't really an answer.